# Global function works in preview but fails when code is run

Tags: anypoint-studio, dataweave, cloudhub, mulesoft

I have a global function named 'finalPrice' which is defined in my configuration.xml file.
The function takes in a value - does stuff to it - and returns the final value. I reference the function from within DataWeave. When I click 'preview' I can see the correct output in the preview window. However when I run it I get the error:

---

Message               : Exception while executing:

There is no variable named 'finalPrice'.

---

I have run the code on my local machine and in CloudHub and I get the same result

XML Code:

```
<configuration doc:name="Configuration">
        <expression-language>
            <global-functions>
                <!-- This function is called by the 'Validate and Transform' dataweave component in the 'main' flow-->
                def finalPrice(incoming_value) 
                {
                    import java.lang.String;
                    import java.math.RoundingMode;

                    // Do Stuff

                    return strFinalNumber;
                }
            </global-functions>
        </expression-language>
</configuration>
```

DataWeave Code:

```
//Refer to "finalPrice" Global Function in the main.xml configuration file
DB_FINL_PRCE: "field_missing" when payload01.DB_FINL_PRCE == "" otherwise finalPrice(payload01.DB_FINL_PRCE)
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an issue with the comments in the global-functions. So remove or modify the line:

```
 <!-- This function is called by the 'Validate and Transform' dataweave component in the 'main' flow-->
```

and just have:

```
<configuration doc:name="Configuration">
            <expression-language>
                <global-functions>
                    def finalPrice(incoming_value) 
                    {
                        import java.lang.String;
                        import java.math.RoundingMode;

                        // Do Stuff

                        return strFinalNumber;
                    }
                </global-functions>
            </expression-language>
    </configuration>
```

Or modify your comments to //

```
<configuration doc:name="Configuration">
        <expression-language autoResolveVariables="true">
            <global-functions>
                //This function is called by the 'Validate and Transform' dataweave component in the 'main' flow
                def finalPrice(incoming_value) 
                {

                    // Do Stuff

                    return "somethingelse";
                }
            </global-functions>
        </expression-language>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thank you very much